# Cooling by radiation in space

Tags: radiation

Let's say that you have a gram of molten gallium in the vacuum of space just floating about. how fast would It cool back to a solid via radiation?

Comment: Are you specifically interested in gallium?  And what temperature is this gallium at initially?  The equations governing [radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_radiation) are straight forward, but you do need to plug in a whole bunch of specifics to get an exact answer.

Comment: I only said gallium because the low temp that it melts at but I really just want to know how to calculate how fast a substance would cool via radiation.

Comment: @T.Fisher Newton's law of cooling would be a place to start.  If you add a phase change, then you have the additional complication of latent heat of melting. And are you close enough to a star for its radiation to be a factor on one side of the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equations you are looking for are on the [Thermal Radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_radiation) page of Wikipedia.  The general version is that you have to integrate across all wavelengths at your given temperature for a black body:

$u(\lambda,T)=\frac{2 h c^2}{\lambda^5}\cdot\frac1{e^{hc/k_BT\lambda}-1}$

Where most of the letters you see there are constants:

- $h$ - Plank's Constant
- $h_b$ - Boltzman's Constant
- $c$ - speed of light

You have to do this integration across all wavelengths.  Now one trick to this, which is why I asked about Gallium in the comments, is that no real object is actually a black body (perfect radiator).  They radiate less, and they often radiate less in a frequency dependent way that requires a large number of calculations specific to the material.  This number is known as the emissivity of the material $\epsilon(\nu)$.  However, if we're looking for order of magnitude type numbers, we can make the assumption that our object is a "grey body," which has a frequency-independent knockdown factor away from a perfect black body behavior, $\epsilon$.  In this case, we can simplify things by integrating across all wavelengths for you and arrive at a very useful equation:

$P = \epsilon \cdot \sigma \cdot A \cdot T^4$

In this equation:

- $P$ - power emitted via radiation
- $\epsilon$ - emissivity of your material ([this document](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19860006789.pdf) from NASA suggets 0.1 to 0.3 are good numbers for Gallium)
- $\sigma$ - Stefan–Boltzmann constant ($5.670 373 (21)\times10^{−8}\;\text W\cdot\text m^{−2}\cdot\text K^{−4}$)
- $A$ - surface area of your object
- $T$ - temperature of your object.

So all you need to do is look at the power output versus the heat capacity and surface area of your gallium (at whatever temperature you choose).  Note there's a square-cubed law here.  The heat capacity will increase by a cubic (because its based on volume), while the power emitted will grow by a square (based on surface area).  Large objects will cool slower than small objects.

One minor detail: In theory you need to account for both power radiated out and power radiated in from the cold of space.  Space is around 2K, so it does radiate some heat back.  However, given that the radiation grows by the 4th power of temperature, for temperatures you are interested in this effect will be negligible (especially compared to your unknowns in emissivity), so you can ignore it.  However, if you are later interested in doing the same calculations to calculate how long it takes to cool down to close to the temperature of space, you'll need to factor that in.